# SQL Server: Could not find prepared statement with handle 10 from query analizer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run the SQL profiler and I want to run some of the queries in the query analyser but I get an error "SQL Server: Could not find prepared statement with handle x".

Any ideas?

This is the SQL I have copied from the profiler:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=10
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P0 int,@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 datetime,@P3 datetime,@P4 datetime,@P5 datetime,@P6 datetime,@P7 datetime',N'SELECT * FROM SCHEDULE WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE RoomNo= @P0  AND STATUS =  @P1   AND ( (EndTimeDT <=  @P2  AND EndTimeDT >  @P3 ) OR (StartTimeDT >=  @P4  AND StartTimeDT <  @P5 )  OR (StartTimeDT <=  @P6  AND EndTimeDT >  @P7 ) )',1
select @p1
go
exec sp_execute 10,19,N'A','2012-03-22 16:30:00','2012-03-22 16:00:00','2012-03-22 16:00:00','2012-03-22 16:30:00','2012-03-22 16:00:00','2012-03-22 16:30:00'
go
```

Comment: In the corresponding *RPC:Starting* event, the text data probably contains `set @p1=NULL`. [Smith's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22495122/173497) mentions this.

Comment: FYI - This looks like how Cognos passes a query to SQL Server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you need to modify the profiler text if you want to run it in the query analizer.

```
declare @p1 int
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P0 int,@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 datetime,@P3 datetime,@P4 datetime,@P5 datetime,@P6 datetime,@P7 datetime',N'SELECT * FROM SCHEDULE WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE RoomNo= @P0  AND STATUS =  @P1   AND ( (EndTimeDT <=  @P2  AND EndTimeDT >  @P3 ) OR (StartTimeDT >=  @P4  AND StartTimeDT <  @P5 )  OR (StartTimeDT <=  @P6  AND EndTimeDT >  @P7 ) )',1
select @p1
exec sp_execute @p1,19,N'A','2012-03-22 16:30:00','2012-03-22 16:00:00','2012-03-22 16:00:00','2012-03-22 16:30:00','2012-03-22 16:00:00','2012-03-22 16:30:00'
go
```

Comment: When you say 'modify the profiler text' do you mean specifically 'delete the set statements for variables used in the output' (i.e. remove the `set @p1=10` line)?

Answer (score 20):

You should use `RPC:Starting` queries not `RPC:Completed`

In profiler you would normally see `RPC:Starting` and `RPC:Completed`. The statement shown in `RPC:Staring` is what you need to pick, `RPC:Completed` would include output values that were not passed from the client.

If you use `RPC:Completed` you should remove SET `set @p1=10` the queries to work

Comment: By default, `RPC:Starting` events are not traced. When starting a new trace, you need to check 'Show all events' and check `RPC:Starting`.

Answer (score 16):

this is my second answer, I misunderstood the question when I wrote the first one.

Why are you doing `set @p1=10`? You are not supposed to set this variable. try removing it